# How could I abort an awaited task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation-token

I have recently very quickly learned that all a `Cancellation` token, in my context, is worth is to prevent the task from being scheduled. I have long running, single method tasks that I need to abort in the awaited task. How can I achieve this?

My first idea is to let rip another thread for the long running method, but above that have a loop that keeps checking if `Cancellation.IsCancelled == true`, and when it is `true`, I abort the thread hosting the long running method.

Is this bad? Is there some other way?

BTW, my long running task is a single method, so I can either check the cancellation token before it starts running, or after it's run, leaving me no opportunity to stop the long running method before it finishes, e.g, collection all `FileInfo` objects for every file on  drive C:! This is the long running code:

```
FileInfos = Mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<FileInfoViewModel>>(dirInfo.GetFiles($"*.{ext.TrimStart('.')}", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

I could split that into two calls, and check the token between them, but that won't have much effect, or I can rewrite CLR code into my own, and manually use loops that check the token. That will work, but it smells very bad.

Comment: [Yes, it's bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort). Calling `Thread.Abort()` should be treated as a bug. You need to do co-operative cancellation - the thread being cancelled needs to periodically check if it's been cancelled, and react accordingly. If it can't do that, then it's probably safer to just abandon it.

Comment: You'll have to describe what your task does and why cancellation token isn't usable

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Please see my edit.

Comment: You can fake cancel uninterruptible code by isolating it and making the main code continue anyway, e.g. Task.WhenAny(actualWork, someCancellation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying system API used for enumerating file system entities already supports cancellation - you just have to make sure to use the correct managed API.

`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` will transform the enumerable to an array - which means it only returns when all the data has been collected. On the other hand, `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` will expose the enumerable directly, and you can easily stop evaluation at any point.

There's still a few bits that will not be interruptible, but `Thread.Abort` wouldn't help you there anyway - `Thread.Abort` only kills threads when they're in managed code, and all the things that actually take time are native, using the `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` APIs.